# linear regression python from a table

Tags: linear-regression

I have a very simple table with two columns weight and height, and I have imported from a table into Python (PyCharm).
How can I get the linear regressions paramaters, R-value and a basic graph with data?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

print('basetable')
basetable = pd.read_excel('C:/pythonfiles/wieght_height_data.xlsx',
                              engine='openpyxl',
                              sheet_name='wieght_height_data')
print(basetable)
print('')
```

basetable

| weight | height |
| --- | --- |
| 54 | 162 |
| 62 | 154 |
| ... | ... |

It would be great just see the parameters of the line, y = b + m*x and other metrics.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution

```
x = basetable['weight'].to_numpy()
y = basetable['height'].to_numpy()
gradient, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
mn=np.min(x)
mx=np.max(x)
x1=np.linspace(mn,mx,500)
y1=gradient*x1+intercept
print("gradient: ",round(gradient,2))
print("intersept: ",round(intercept,2))
print("r_value: ",round(r_value,4))
print("p_value: ",round(p_value,4))
print("std_err: ",round(std_err,4))
plt.plot(x,y,'ob')
plt.plot(x1,y1,'-r')
plt.show()
```